# how to compare 2 set in java containing characters in it?

Tags: java, char, set, compare

I have 2 sets:

```
Set<Character> set1 = new HashSet<>();
Set<Character> set2 = new HashSet<>();
```

`set1` contains `[txt file]`, `set2` contains `[a,e,i,o,u]`.

I want to compare both the sets and find the numbers of vowels in the text file.

Comment: do we have to extract each characters from the text file and compare it with set2? if not then how can we compare char to strings?

Answer (score 0):

1. Using **guava**

   Sets.intersection(set1, set2).size()
2. Using **apache commons collection**

   CollectionUtils.intersection(collection1, collection2).size()
3. Using **gs-collections**

   mutableSet1.intersect(mutableSet2).size()
4. Using **plan JDK**

   Set result = new HashSet<>(set1);

   result.retainAll(set2);

   result.size();